# How can I add a button under my mobile logo?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

This is the website [HERE](http://australianscaffolds.com.au)

I am wondering how I can go about adding text or a button directly under my logo specifically on mobile devices?

I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with clearly stating what your desired **result** is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

Look into your theme's header.php file, you'd have to add media query to make it display on mobile devices only.

Search for "header_top_bottom_holder" class in header.php to get the correct block.

Also, make sure you've your child theme set up first.

Cheers,